# Access Compare Database Schema

Tags: database, ms-access, compare

I want to compare two Access database and check is there any field or type mismatch within that or not.

Is there any way we can check that using dataset or is there a faster way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Free Database Compare 2.0 ([review](http://rbytes.net/software/free-database-compare-review/)) by StarInix Software to compare.

Comment: It is really cool tool. However I did not find the option to synchronize two databases :(

Comment: Your link is dead but I think this is the product you were pointing to:  [link](https://icoder.azurewebsites.net/sqlcompare02.htm)

Answer (score 3):

1. Use the Access database Documenter (Tools\Analyze\Documenter) to create a report of your database objects.
2. Export this report as a text file (right-click in report, Export..., Save as type Text Files).

Do this for each of your databases and compare the text files using your diff tool of choice.

Answer (score 1):

I've been Access Pro Table Compare.  I found it online and it has worked great for comparing MS Access tables, finding field and datatype issues, etc.

[Access Pro Table Compare Tool](http://www.db-pros.com/AccessPro)

Comment: Are you associated with the makers of this piece of software? It seems rather suspicious that the only time you've ever posted on SO is this particular recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the system tables in the access database (which are hidden by default) just the way you would in a SQL Server database, but using the ODBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

I've made an [AccdbMerge](https://ksdbmerge.tools/microsoft-access-diff-merge-overview.html) utility that allows to compare Access objects and data. In scope of schema comparison - it allows to compare list of tables and queries and each table/query definition.

Answer (score -1):

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command14_Click()

Dim tablename1, tablename2, field_date As String
tablename1 = Text10.Value
tablename2 = Text13.Value
flter_date = Text16.Value
length = Len(tablename1) - Len("gahpu00d_")
field_date = Right(tablename1, length) & "_posted_dt"

'On Error GoTo Err_cmdValidateGeneralInfo_Click

 Dim F As DAO.Field
 Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Set curDB = CurrentDb()

DoCmd.CopyObject , "Unmatched_records", acTable, tablename1
curDB.Execute "DELETE FROM Unmatched_records"


 'to calculate count of filtered data in staged

strsql = "Select * from " & tablename1 & " where cdate(" & field_date & ") = """ & flter_date & """ order by " & field_date & ""
DoCmd.RunSQL "Select * into filter_data1 from " & tablename1 & " where cdate(" & field_date & ") = """ & flter_date & """"
count_data1 = DCount(field_date, "filter_data1")
Text18.Enabled = True
Text18.Value = count_data1

'to calculate count of filtered data in production

strsql1 = "Select * from " & tablename2 & " where cdate(" & field_date & ") = """ & flter_date & """ order by " & field_date & ""
DoCmd.RunSQL "Select * into filter_data2 from " & tablename2 & " where cdate(" & field_date & ") = """ & flter_date & """"
count_data2 = DCount(field_date, "filter_data2")
Text20.Enabled = True
Text20.Value = count_data2

If count_data1 <> count_data2 Then
If count_data1 > count_data2 Then
  MsgBox "The number of records in the table didnt match." & tablename1 & " has more records than " & tablename2
  Exit Sub

  Else
  MsgBox "The number of records in the table didnt match." & tablename2 & " has more records than " & tablename1
  Exit Sub

End If
End If

Set rs = curDB.OpenRecordset(strsql)
Set rs1 = curDB.OpenRecordset(strsql1)


    Do Until rs.EOF
      For Each F In rs.Fields


        If rs.Fields(F.Name) <> rs1.Fields(F.Name) Then
          'rs.Edit
          strsql = "Select * into test from " & tablename1 & " where " & F.Name & " = """ & rs.Fields(F.Name) & """"
          DoCmd.RunSQL strsql

          If DCount(F.Name, "test") <> 0 Then
          GoTo append_unmatch

          'appending unmacthed records
append_unmatch:

          strsql2 = "insert into Unmatched_records Select * from test"
          DoCmd.RunSQL strsql2

          'if record doesnt match move to next one
          GoTo Nextrecord
          End If
         ' rs.Fields(F.Name) = rs1.Fields(F.Name)
         ' rs.Update
        End If
      Next F

Nextrecord:
rs.MoveNext
rs1.MoveNext
    Loop


     'To check whether tables matched or not
final:
    Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
    strsql3 = "select * from Unmatched_records"
    Set rs2 = curDB.OpenRecordset(strsql3)
    For Each F In rs2.Fields
    If DCount(F.Name, "Unmatched_records") <> 0 Then
    MsgBox ("The two tables didnt match. Check table Unmatched_records for unmatching reocrds.")
    Else
    MsgBox ("Tables match!")
    End If
Exit Sub
   Next F
    rs2.Close


End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
Text20.Enabled = False
Text18.Enabled = False
Text18.Value = ""
Text20.Value = ""
End Sub
```